# IE 8 can´t show the page after one hour

Tags: internet-explorer, struts2

I use Internet Explorer 8 to test my struts 2 aplicattion with IE7 view . When an action takes more than one hour, the browser shows a message or error: " Internet Explorer can´t show the web page".  If the action take less than one hour everything goes fine. The issue is not happening with Mozila-Firefox.

Any ideas why IE is doing this, please??

Regards.

Comment: If something is taking more than an hour in a web application, there is something bad going on there. You should at least do ajax keepalive...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/181050)

> Internet Explorer imposes a time-out limit for the server to return
>   data. By default, the time-out limit is as follows:
>
> [...]
>
> Internet Explorer 7 & 8 : **60 minutes**
>
> When the server is experiencing a problem, Internet Explorer does not
>   wait endlessly for the server to return data.